# Is it possible to export from display form in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, excel, display-form

Can we export a particular record to excel from SharePoint 2013 display form of a list record using jQuery? Please let me know if it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you can. Maybe you can try to use table2excel plugin with jQuery.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel.html